# Mihtril.redraw method not working in Electron event handler

Tags: javascript, electron, mithril.js

I'm trying to recreate the native Windows controls and the application titlebar in an Electron app. I've created separate components that I include in my main project and use them.

The following code is for the maximize / unmaximize window control. Clicking on the icon itself triggers a redraw and the icon changes from maximize to unmaximize and vice versa. I'd like the icon to also change when the window is maximized / unmaximized by other means (double-clicking the titlebar, dragging the window to the top of the screen...).

For this, I'm using the `'maximize'` and `'unmaximize'` events on the `Electron.BrowserWindow` itself, but calling `m.redraw` from these handlers doesn't seem to actually trigger the redraw.

This is my code:

```
'use strict';
const electron = require('electron');
const m = require('mithril');

const browserWindow = electron.remote.getCurrentWindow();

browserWindow.on('maximize', () => {
    m.redraw();
});

browserWindow.on('unmaximize', () => {
    m.redraw();
});

const Maximize = {
    view: vnode => m('.app-window-controls-button.app-window-controls-button-maximize', {
        tabindex: -1,
        onclick: e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (browserWindow.isMaximized()) {
                browserWindow.unmaximize();
            } else {
                browserWindow.maximize();
            }
        }
    }, [
            browserWindow.isMaximized() ? 'unmaximize icon' : 'maximize icon'
        ]
    )
};

module.exports = Maximize;
```

I can't see any errors in the main process or the renderer process.

So far, I've tried calling `redraw` in a timeout, through method on `vnode.state`, in `requestAnimationFrame`, tried using an attribute on `vnode.state` to track the window maximized state instead of directly reading it from `browserWindow`, nothing seems to work.

*Electron v1.7.9; Mithril 1.1.5.*

Comment: If you change your `view` method to include a `console.log("Maximixed?", browserWindow.isMaximized())` call what does it show when toggling maximized state?

Comment: On first render, it is `Maximized? false`, toggling maximized state by clicking on the icon itself triggers the output again, showing `true` when the window was maximized and `false` when it was unmaximized. Toggling maximized state using other means doesn't trigger the `console.log` call at all, however putting another `console.log` into the event handlers themselves, I can see the output in the console (so the handlers are being called, just `redraw` isn't).

Comment: Is mithril already running before those event handlers are being called? Without being able to see and poke at it I'm not sure what else might be causing it. If you add a `debugger` statement to the `browserWindow.on()` handlers can you step into the `m.redraw` call and see where it gets lost?

Comment: Turns out that there were actually two instances of Mithril running at the same time. One used by the main app (this is the one calling `m.mount`), the other used by the "controls" component (which I was calling `m.redraw` on). The `click` listener did trigger the redraw of the main instance, as it was rendered by it, but the call to `m.redraw` in `maximize` and `unmaximize` listeners was calling `redraw` on the second instance. After making sure that only one instance of Mithril is used everywhere, it is now working as expected.

Comment: @ROAL how did you ensure there was only one insance running? Why were there two before? Feel free to add an answer to your question so it's easy to find for anyone who has the same problem.